# Selectlist and dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to create a dropdownlist from following structure

```
List<KeyValuePair<long, string>> sponsori = 
    new List<KeyValuePair<long, string>>();
```

Now I want the selectlist to have the pair's long as data value, the string as text value and the selected item, if I have only access to the long of the selected item.

THanks in advance.

Comment: See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action code

```
 yourViewModel.Sponsori= new SelectList(sponsori, "Key", "Value")
```

In your view code

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("yourSelectid", Model.Sponsori) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewData["selectList"] = new SelectList(sponsori, "Key", "Value");
```

And then on the page:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("selectList") %>
```

You can also check out Rendering a Form in [ASP.NET MVC Using HTML Helpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx) for a similar example (and more documentation).